# Where to put filter form code in zf2 MVC pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I’ve added a small form to an index view to allow users to filter the data.  I have placed the following code for the form inside the controller, but I question whether this is the right place to put it.

```
// ...

public function indexAction()

    // ...

    // build group list
    $groupList = array(
        0  => 'all',
        1  => 'short people',
        2  => 'tall people',
        3  => 'fun people',
        4  => 'boring people',
    );

    // create group selection box
    $groupSelect = new Element\Select('group');
    $groupSelect->setValueOptions($groupList);
    $groupSelect->setAttributes(array(
       'onChange' => 'this.form.submit()',
    ));

    // create filter form
    $form = new Form('group-filter');
    $form->add($groupSelect);
    $form->setData(array(
        'group' => $group,
    ));

    // process the form
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $groupSelection  = $request->getPost('group', 0);
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin-members', array('group'=>$groupSelection,));
    }

    // ...
```

Following the MVC pattern, does all of this code belong in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Nope it does not belong in the controller. Create a new form class (that extends `Zend\Form\Form`) and inject into the controller class. You can do that through the controllers factory, either through a factory class or the anonymous function "factory".

Other way to do it would be to get it (the form you created) in the controller from the service manager, but as far I know that's not the recommended method anymore, even though it still in the ZF2 [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html).

That way your form code will be separated from the controller code, not mixing with the actual controller logic and, in the former case, also more easily testable.

You can learn more from this ZF2 forum [thread](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ZF2-Injecting-objects-to-a-controller-or-getting-objects-from-the-service-locator-td4656872.html). It's lengthy, but there are code samples and lead devs from ZF2 team are weighing in.